# convert php array to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html, web

I am working with laravel, and i get a list of values from a database with this code:

```
$idordenes = DB::table('ordenes')->select('id')->get();
```

when I echo de idordenes variable I get this:

```
[{"factoryid":233658},{"factoryid":566981},{"factoryid":889566},{"factoryid":114789},{"factoryid":256958},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":599544},{"factoryid":222364},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":555696},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},{"factoryid":0},
```

I want to covert this in a javascript array like this:

```
var ordenes = [233658,566981,889566,114789,...];
```

I hope the help. thanks

Comment: `echo json_encode(array_column($idordenes, 'factoryid'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const arr = [{"factoryid":233658},{"factoryid":566981},{"factoryid":889566},{"factoryid":114789},{"factoryid":256958},/* more element */];

let newArr = arr.map(elem=>elem.factoryid);

console.log(newArr);
```

But your mean is code in `php` or `js` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ajax get request to get the data from php to your javascript file. You can use jQuery to make an ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax(
  url: "path_to_your_php_file",
  success: data => {
    var ordenes = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(ordenes); // Ordenes is now the array in javascript
  }
);
```

In your **php file** you must "send out" the data you wish the ajax call to receive. You can do this by doing the following:

`echo json_encode(array_column($idordenes, 'factoryid'));`